# How do I play Urban Terror with bots?

Tags: urban-terror

I'm loving urban terror, but sometimes I just want to play it "offline." Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. To add bots to a game:

- First tell the server to allow bots, press tilde (~) to open the console and type:

  `/bot_enable 1` and start the server through the appropriate menu choices
- If the server is already running, type:

  `/reload` then you can start to add the bot(s):
- To add a bot, use the command:

  `/addbot <type> <level> <team> <ping> <server nick>`

  - The `<type>` should use one of the following bot file names:

    - boa
    - cheetah
    - chicken
    - cobra
    - c ockroach (<== space between the C and the O added to pass BB filters)
    - cougar
    - goose
    - mantis
    - penguin
    - puma
    - python
    - raven
    - scarab
    - scorpion
    - tiger
    - widow
  - The `<level>` should be an integer between 1 (*n00bish*) – 5 (*malevolent*)
  - The `<team>` should be either Blue, or Red
  - The `<ping>` is just a placeholder, put 76 in
  - The `<server nick>` should be what you want to name the bot
- To recap, the following would add a level 4 bot called “ThePuma” to the blue team:

  `/addbot Puma 4 Blue 76 ThePuma`

  Each bot type has it’s own weapon load out – Puma for example uses a LR300ML + Spas + Baretta combo. By making sure at least 1 bot has the same weapons as you, you’ll never run out of ammo.

  Tactically, the bots are not very bright, and you can’t give them orders like q3 bots, however they do use the same evasion techniques (varying levels of crouching, bunny hopping and strafing) as live players, with varying levels of aggression.

Bot configuration files

- If you want to add more than one bot at a time, you might want to make a .cfg file which you save to your q3ut4 directory

```
/====== sample_bot.cfg======

addbot C ockroach 4 Blue 76 =lvl4=C ockroach 

addbot Cheetah 4 Blue 56 =lvl4=Cheetah

addbot Cobra 4 Blue 45 =lvl4=Cobra

addbot Penguin 4 Blue 89 =lvl4=Penguin

addbot Puma 4 Blue 89 =lvl4=Puma

addbot Puma 1 Blue 89 =lvl1=Puma


/====== sample_bot.cfg======
```

- Get the server to load this by simply typing:

  `/exec <filename>`

  - Note while the example above tries to add bots to the blue team – the server will spread them evenly on both teams – so add an even number or face the chagrin of continually getting pwned at spawn, by bots.
  - As mentioned before, the bots mimic certain aspects of real life, in teams they will mimic certain aspects of team life, like occasionally tking you for no reason, ignoring calls for backup or medic, and appearing to be AFK at spawn.

Removing bots:

`/kick <nick>`

- If you have more than 1 bot, or you can’t be arsed typing whatever l33t nick you gave that 1 bot you added, you can use this to take all bots off the server:

  `/kick allbots`

  - though be warned the server checks for nick matches in the player list first, so player ‘allbots’ would probably not be too happy with you, having been bumrushed off the server for no apparent reason.

Maps for running bots

- Not every map in UT4 has bot support, the following do, sort of:

  - Abbey
  - Algiers
  - Austria
  - Dressing room
  - Firing Range
  - Mandolin *
  - Riyadh
  - Prague*
  - Toxic*
  - Uptown
- Some maps work better than others – the maps marked with an asterisk are maps where the bots have trouble getting out of the spawn points.
- The maps found most useful in upping my game are :

  - Firing range - good for close quarters practice
  - Riyadh – add several bots for sniper target practice
  - Algiers – for finding sweet spots on the map to fire from cover
  - Dressing room – for mixed terrain levels + varying range battles – though bots will fall into the river in the middle and remain in there.

and again:
[Basic tutorial on bot setup](http://namchangkorpa.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/adding-bots-in-urban-terror/), [detailed bot info and gear](http://www.thinkdigit.com/forum/gamerz/62954-can-play-urban-terror-single-mode.html), and [setting up configs(easy bot addition)](http://www.urbanterror.info/forums/topic/19892-addbot-for-ut/).

Comment: I did tha("\addbot Penguin 3 Blue 10 firstbot"), but it says the bot name is not defined. It's the same with other names :(

Comment: @madTux it should be /, not \ before addbot

Comment: This answer looks to be plagiarised from [here](http://www.urbanterror.info/forums/topic/6906-running-bots-in-ut4/) without attribution (including the changing spelling of cockroach to bypass filters we do not have here). Content like this should be attributed.

Comment: @AshleyNunn The first link I attributed links to the urbanterror forums